# C++ stringstream to char* conversion memory allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, stringstream, istringstream

Can anyone explain how the following code is working and does **not** crash the application?

```
int main() {
    char *tempStr = new char[5];
    tempStr[0] = '\0';
    string stemp = "helloworld";
    stringstream sstream;
    sstream.str(stemp);
    cout << "len before = " << strlen(tempStr);
    sstream >> tempStr;
    cout << "len after = " << strlen(tempStr) << endl;
    cout << tempStr << endl;
    delete[] tempStr;
    return 1;
}
```

I am getting the output as

```
len before = 0
len after = 10
helloworld
```

1. Did `stringstream` allocate memory for the extra characters in the char pointer?
2. Also want to know the correct way to copy data from `stringstream` to char* array, without exceeding the memory allocated for `char*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Did stringstream allocate memory for the extra characters in the char pointer?

No. Your code invokes undefined behavior.

> Also want to know the correct way to copy data from stringstream to char* array, without exceeding the memory allocated for char*?

It is not a good idea to read into `char*`. Use `std::string` to read input from stream. But then if you still want to know for the sake of knowledge, use [`std::istream::read()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read).

```
if ( sstream.read(tempStr, 5 ) )
{
   //read succeeded
}
```

---

By the way, you can merge these two lines:

```
stringstream sstream;
sstream.str(stemp);
```

into one:

```
stringstream sstream(stemp);
```

or simply this:

```
stringstream sstream("helloworld"); //no need of stemp!
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can we also do `sstream << stemp`?

Comment: Yes, since it is `stringstream` which is both for input and output.

Comment: i have a requirement, cant use string. so the only way is use `istream::read` and specify the max length of your char array. Thanks.

Comment: actually i was reading both `integer` and `char*` datatypes with `>> operator` in a `macro`. Is there a way to still do that without doing differently for `integer` and `char*`.

Comment: @N3Xg3N: I didn't understand what you're saying? What is `macro` here? Post your code at ideone.com or pastebin.com

Comment: `#define INPUT_STRUCT_DATA(data,strct_mbr)\
                        {stringstream inp(data); \
      inp >> strct_mbr; \
      inp.str(string()); \
      inp.clear();}` i am passing a string in the first param and a struct member in the second, can be int or char*

Comment: @N3Xg3N: Why don't you experiment with them writing some small programs? That would also help you understand things better.

Comment: of course tried writing snippets of code, was trying to achieve reflection by filling in struct data using stringstream `operator >>`. may not be a simple way

Answer (score 1):

1. No. You overwrote memory, invoking undefined behavior, but nothing obvious happened, so the error went unnoticed. There is no requirement that doing something like this should trigger any kind of human-visible error or special action, thus the wording *undefined behavior*.
2. You're going to have to do it chunk by chunk, and re-allocate the `char` array if it runs out of space. In C++, there's little point in doing this manually. Just use `std::string` and be done.